# Issues calculating range with QGIS 2.0 raster calculator

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I would like to calculate a simple range using the QGIS 2.0 Raster Calculator, but am getting strange results. I believe I am not using the correct syntax.

To get all values between .003-.5, I entered the following:
[image]

This resulted in the following raster:

[image]

As I found this result very strange, I decided to check all values above .003:
[image]

This resulted in the following raster, which I believed to make sense. It is simply the inverse of the first without any overlap, meaning I am unable to target all values within my needed range:
[image]

When attempting with AND logic, I got a completely black raster image:
[image]

Now, I've tried to fix the issue by separating the categories completely. The raster is still black.
[image]

Elevation greater than 5:
[image]

Elevation greater than .03. Note, that I happened to test .03 instead of .003 in this case as opposed to previous screen captures:
[image]

I'm just looking to have the elevation between these two values.

Comment: What if you put your two expressions in parentheses - `(> .003) AND (< .5)`? Or use a leading 0 before your decimal? And I'm assuming it's verified there *are* values in that range in the raster. I also can't tell if the quotes are needed around the raster name - the documentation seems to contradict itself (screenshot vs code formatted expression examples), and other examples I see don't use them.

Comment: @ChrisW Yes, the values are confirmed using another software. Adding the parenthesis in this way is considered "invalid" by qgis.

Comment: You definitely need to split the two arguments with a logic operator - that much I'm sure on. But the more documenation I look at, the more confused I get about the remaining syntax. Can you try `(taharuu_GRASSrst@1 < 0.003) OR (taharuu_GRASSrst@1 > 0.5) = 0` and see if that works? Then add quotes around the raster name if it doesn't? And if *that* still doesn't work, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @ChrisW I wish that worked too. I'm very puzzled...

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more assistance. My suggestion was based on a [blog post](http://linfiniti.com/2012/01/simple-binary-raster-reclassification-in-qgis/) I'd found. I also noted a potential alternative approach in the QGIS training manual at the bottom of [section 16.10](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/processing/no_data.html) using an IF statement. Your results so far suggest to me there are no values in that range, but you've verified that already so I can't think of anything else aside from posting the raster for people to test with if you can.

Comment: @ChrisW Thanks for directing me to this blog post, I hadn't tried with else. Using your suggestion doesn't give me a black screen, but gives me only values >.03 = 1, it doesn't give me values <= 5 as well.

Comment: @ChrisW I added screen captures from QGIS of data above .03 and data above .5, and there is definitely overlap. Unfortunately, I can't post the raster itself.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting expected results with the `"taharuu_grass_rst@1" >0.003 and "taharuu_grass_rst@1"< 0.5` expression.  You are using boolean operators, so getting boolean results, (i.e. 1 & 0).  To actually extract the values in that range, multiply by the original raster band.

```
("taharuu_grass_rst@1" >0.003 and "taharuu_grass_rst@1"< 0.5) * "taharuu_grass_rst@1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expression should be

```
"taharuu_grass_rst@1" >=0.003 and "taharuu_grass_rst@1"<= 0.5
```

Comment: I just tried that and it still gives me a black screen. Are you trying to point out the leading zero, the minuscule "and" or the >= vs >? If it's the last, then I'm wondering how i'll be able to set the ranges correctly without overlap.

Comment: The important part is splitting it into two separate criteria, joined with an "and". Can you post your updated expression?

Comment: i've now added a screen capture with the separate categories. could > .003 and <= .5 technically work?